# Google Calendar - Add an event

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I was using the URL format based on Google Calendar API V2 to add an event to the calendar, which basically opens up a form with all detail filled in it, for ex:

[Add Event](http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Event+Desc&dates=20140829T080000Z/20140829T080000Z&details=&location=&trp=false)

But, as API V2 is going to be deprecated from 17th November, 2014 onwards, I need something similar with API V3. From what I understood from the API documentation that I need to use OAuth to authorize the user and then I need the calendar ID to add the event directly to calendar, but, I just want to display the form(with details in it) as it used to work with API V2. Can I do it without the OAuth\Calendar ID?

Comment: Add Event is safe from the deprecation. You can keep using it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old URLs for adding calendar events are still valid.

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Event+Desc
```